# Mysql query with multiple ID columns and php

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have 2 joined tables, each one has a primary key column named id.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* from t1 join t2 on t1.fk_id=t2.id
```

When I run the query above, both id fields are selected (t1.id and t2.id).  My question is, how can I select the correct ID while I am looping through the result set?  If I select $result->id, I will get the t2.id.  Is there any way that I can get the t1.id also without explicitly selecting it in the query (i.e. t1.id as t1_id?)  Also, please, let us know about some of your practices when it comes to naming the primary key columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t1.*, t2.* from t1 join t2 on t1.fk_id=t2.id
```

Comment: This allows you to reference the columns using `id1` and `id2` (or whatever you set the `as xxx` to)

Comment: Thanks to all!  I usually explicitly select my desired columns and am ok with just naming my PKs 'id'.  The project that I have taken over has so many fields and constants for table names that thinking of typing all that stuff just got me lazy.

Answer (score 3):

You'll often see the primary key for table XXX named xxx_id. This keeps the name of the same "information identifier" the same everywhere: for example in another table YYY, you'll have YYY.xxx_id with a foreign key constraint to XXX.xxx_id. This makes joins easier (you don't have to specify the "on" constraint at all in many databases) and it solves the problem you're running into as well.

I'm not saying you should prefix every column name to create a faux-namespace, but in the case of "id" it is actually useful and descriptive. It is, after all, not just any kind of ID, it's a user ID, site ID, game ID, contact ID, what have you.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach myself, as one tends to end up with things like CREATE TABLE my_very_long_table_name (my_very_long_table_name_col1 INT, my_very_long_table_name_col2 INT); which are a pain for everyone for ever more.

Comment: Sorry, that was muddled - I updated the answer. I only meant naming the primary key instead of simply using "id". I didn't mean to use the table name as a prefix to every column. Then again, it's been a while since I wrote my own SQL and didn't manipulate it through some DSL/ORM...

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to return each row of your result set as an associative array.  MySQL will let you have two columns with the same name in a query, but these do not map to an associative array the way you want them to—even though the associative array is doing exactly as it should.

Assume two tables, `book` and `author`, linked by the junction table `book_author`.  In MySQL, you can run the following query, which returns two `id` columns:

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM book AS b
JOIN book_author AS ba ON ba.book_id = b.id
JOIN author AS a ON a.id = ba.author_id
LIMIT 2;

+----+-----------------+----+--------------+
| id | title           | id | name         |
+----+-----------------+----+--------------+
|  1 | Design Patterns |  1 | Erich Gamma  |
|  1 | Design Patterns |  2 | Richard Helm |
+----+-----------------+----+--------------+
```

If you try to map one of these rows to an associative array, you end up with a single `id` element in your array:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row);

Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Design Patterns
    [name] => Erich Gamma
)
```

The last `id` column in the row will overwrite any that precede it.  Here’s the second row from the result set:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [title] => Design Patterns
    [name] => Richard Helm
)
```

This is just the same as modifying the value of an element in an associative array;

```
$row = array();
$row['id'] = 1;
print_r($row);
Array
(
    [id] => 1
)

$row['id'] = 2;
print_r($row);
Array
(
    [id] => 2
)
```

If you give each column a unique name in your query, either by doing so in the table itself, or giving it an alias in the query, the problem is avoided:

```
SELECT b.id AS book_id, b.title,
    a.id AS author_id, a.name
FROM book AS b
JOIN book_author AS ba ON ba.book_id = b.id
JOIN author AS a ON a.id = ba.author_id
LIMIT 2;

+---------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
| book_id | title           | author_id | name         |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 | Design Patterns |         1 | Erich Gamma  |
|       1 | Design Patterns |         2 | Richard Helm |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row);
Array
(
    [book_id] => 1
    [title] => Design Patterns
    [author_id] => 1
    [name] => Erich Gamma
)
```

Alternatively, you could (and almost certainly should) use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead. Although this can get round the problem of duplicate column names, using unique column names in your queries still makes things much easier to read and debug:

```
$sql = 'SELECT b.*, a.* ' .
   'FROM book AS b ' .
   'JOIN book_author AS ba ' .
   'ON ba.book_id = b.id ' .
   'JOIN author AS a ' .
   'ON a.id = ba.author_id';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($book_id, $book_title, $author_id, $author_name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n",
           $book_id,
           $book_title,
           $author_id,
           $author_name);
}
```